# Line up radio buttons

Tags: html

I have the following HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td class=tabTwo vAlign=top>
        <table border=0 cellPadding=0 cellSpacing=0 width=100%>
            <tr>
                <td vAlign=top width=5%>4.</td>
                <td>Test 1?</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width=5%></td>
                <td colSpan=2>a) <input type="radio" name="S1Q4" value="a" id="s1q4a" /> <label for="s1q4a">A</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width=5%></td>
                <td colSpan=2>b) <input type="radio" name="S1Q4" value="b" id="s1q4b" /> <label for="s1q4b">B</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width=5%></td>
                <td colSpan=2>c) <input type="radio" name="S1Q4" value="c" id="s1q4c" /> <label for="s1q4c">C</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width=5%></td>
                <td colSpan=2>d) <input type="radio" name="S1Q4" value="d" id="s1q4d" /> <label for="s1q4d">D</label></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Produces**:

[image]

How do I made the radio buttons align in a straight line? B & C seem crooked.

Comment: Is a table really required here?

Comment: It's part of a larger chunk of code. Maybe for this example it's not but for the entirety it is required.

Comment: The problem with lining up the radio buttons is that they line up differently depending on what OS or display theme the user is running.

Comment: Middle aligning them as per my answer mostly fixes that issue, @Cobra_Fast

Answer (score -1, accepted):

HTML

```
<div class="form-wrapper">
    <div class="radio-choice">
        <span>a) </span>
        <input id="option1" type="radio" name="opt1"/>
        <label for="option1">Option 1</label>
    </div>

    <div class="radio-choice">    
        <span>b) </span> 
        <input id="option2" type="radio" name="opt2"/>
        <label for="option2">Option 2</label>
    </div>

    <div class="radio-choice">
        <span>c) </span> 
        <input id="option3" type="radio" name="opt3"/>
        <label for="option3">Option 3</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.radio-choice * {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.form-wrapper div{
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}

.form-wrapper span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NewwV/1/

Comment: Works great... I guess I will have to remove the TABLE.

Comment: Your example doesn't include the a) b) c), which is what is messing up the alignment: http://jsfiddle.net/rxUWf/

Comment: You should avoid using `<table>`'s for layout, regardless. Even for forms, they are usually not necessary. Semantically speaking, `<table>` should only be used for tabular data.

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to use a table. Put the inputs in their own cell. The letter width of a),b) etc. is what is throwing of the alignment.

I would not use a table though. Your choice.

Answer (score 2):

Your question seemed a little vague but to best my knowledge, the presence of bullets `a) b) c)` in the same cell is causing the problem. Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bTNvA/

I have tried to resolve this by moving bullets to other cell:

```
<tr>
    <td width=5%> a) </td>
    <td colSpan=2> <input type="radio" name="S1Q4" value="a" id="s1q4a" /> <label for="s1q4a">A</label></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Couldn't I use margin to offset the difference?

Comment: You could but IMO unless you are using monospace font margin won't cut it. you could put the bullets in a class `bullets` and assign a `width` to it for consistency.